# Filter a row based on field=variable

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I want to filter on the first field equal to the value of VAR. There is a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384283/how-to-match-a-pattern-given-in-a-variable-in-awk),
whose `~` solution (SOL1) I have not been able to reproduce. However, that [based on `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46284949/9243116) (SOL2) works, but seems contrived. I'm looking for a solution that is more like SOL1.

```
$ cat tmp
a   b   c
d   e   f
g   h   i
$ awk '$1 ~ /d/' tmp
d   e   f
$ VAR='d'
```

SOL1 (FAIL)

```
$ awk '$1~VAR' tmp
a   b   c
d   e   f
g   h   i
```

SOL2 (WORKAROUND)

```
$ CMD='awk '"'"'$1'"~/$VAR/'"
$ echo "$CMD"
awk '$1~/d/'
$ eval "$CMD" tmp
d   e   f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare strings with `==`.

```
VAR="d"
awk -v var="$VAR" '$1==var' file
```

Output:

```
d   e   f
```

---

From `man awk`:

> `-v var=val`: Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  Such  variable  values are available to the BEGIN rule of an AWK program.

Answer (score -2):

```
Done by 2 methods
```

method1:

```
var="d"
sed -n '/'$var'/p' file
```

output

```
d   e   f
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
var="d"
k=open('ooo','r')
for i in k:
    if var in i:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
d   e   f
```

Comment: A risk here is when $var contains anything in $IFS (or contains a forward slash)

Comment: Both solutions fail to restrict the matches to the first field, as required.